# How can I make this Flask App more DRY (connecting to many oauth APIs)?

Tags: python, oauth, flask, dry

I am connecting to several APIs (e.g. Twitter, GitHub, etc.) using `Flask-oauthlib`. Currently, I have each of these services as a separate blueprint. Within the view files for each of the services, there are the same three views: `login`, `authorized`, and `get_token`. The code right now is not very DRY, but I am struggling to understand how to centralize these views (more conceptually).

***How could I make this more DRY? I would like to understand more conceptually rather than someone actually writing the code for me.***

Below are a few items that may be helpful. This is the application structure:

```
- App
    - Services
        - FourSquare BP
        - GitHub BP
        - Twitter BP
        - ...
    - Other BPs
```

The generic API view would likely go under `Services/api_views.py`

Here is an example of one of the API Blueprint view files (Twitter).

```
twitter = Blueprint('twitter', __name__, url_prefix='/twitter')
bp = twitter

bp.api = TwitterAPI()
bp.oauth = bp.api.oauth_app

# Below here is the exact same for each file.

@bp.route('/')
@login_required
def login():
    if current_user.get(bp.name, None):
        return redirect(url_for('frontend.index'))
    return bp.oauth.authorize(callback=url_for('.authorized', _external=True))

@bp.route('/authorized')
@bp.oauth.authorized_handler
def authorized(resp):
    if resp is None:
        flash(u'You denied the request to sign in.')
        return redirect(url_for('frontend.index'))

    if bp.oauth_type == 'oauth2':
        resp['access_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '') 

    current_user[bp.name] = resp
    current_user.save()

    flash('You were signed in to %s' % bp.name.capitalize())
    return redirect(url_for('frontend.index'))

@bp.oauth.tokengetter
def get_token(token=None):
    if bp.oauth_type == 'oauth2':
        return current_user.get(bp.name, None)['access_token']
    return current_user.get(bp.name, None)['oauth_token']
```

I tried just placing the views together in a class then importing those, but was having trouble with the various decorators (the oauth decorators were giving the most trouble).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out something that seems like a good solution to the above issue. Please let me know if this is in fact a good solution.

I decided to use the Flask class-based views. This got me most of the way to just create a class-view for each of the main API functions above:

```
class APILoginView(View):
    decorators = [login_required]

    def __init__(self, blueprint):
        self.blueprint = blueprint

    def dispatch_request(self):
        if current_user.get(self.blueprint.name, None):
            return redirect(url_for('frontend.index'))
        return self.blueprint.oauth.authorize(callback=url_for('.authorized', _external=True))

class APIAuthorizedView(View):
    decorators = [login_required]

    def __init__(self, blueprint):
        self.blueprint = blueprint

    def dispatch_request(self, resp):
        if resp is None:
            flash(u'You denied the request to sign in.')
            return redirect(url_for('frontend.index'))

        if self.blueprint.api.oauth_type == 'oauth2':
            resp['access_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '') #need to make it a tuple for oauth2 requests

        current_user[self.blueprint.name] = resp
        current_user.save()

        flash('You were signed in to %s' % self.blueprint.name.capitalize())
        return redirect(url_for('frontend.index'))
```

That was the easier part. The trickier thing was figuring out how to generalize the `tokengetter`, required for the Flask-OAuthLib library. Here is what I ended up with:

```
class APIToken():
    def __init__(self, blueprint):
        self.blueprint = blueprint

    def get_token(self, token=None):
        if self.blueprint.api.oauth_type == 'oauth2':
            return current_user.get(self.blueprint.name, None)['access_token']
        return current_user.get(self.blueprint.name, None)['oauth_token']
```

And finally, create a function to register those views on a blueprint:

```
def registerAPIViews(blueprint):
    login_view = APILoginView.as_view('login', blueprint=blueprint)
    auth_view = blueprint.oauth.authorized_handler(
                        APIAuthorizedView.as_view('authorized', blueprint=blueprint))

    blueprint.add_url_rule('/', view_func=login_view)
    blueprint.add_url_rule('/authorized', view_func=auth_view)

    apiToken = APIToken(blueprint)
    token_getter = blueprint.oauth.tokengetter(apiToken.get_token)

    return blueprint
```